# IntelliJ syntax highlighting for PHP

Tags: intellij, syntax-highlighting

I installed IntelliJ IDEA on Ubuntu 16.04 to use Symfony. There is syntax highlighting for .yml files, but there is no syntax highlighting for .php files. How to add syntax highlighting for .php files in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only available in the Ultimate edition of IntelliJ, see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/php.html